# While deploying a WAR file into Azure Web Service, It is not showing in the server URL, but pipeline ran Successfully

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

I am deploying a WAR file into an app server of Azure, My pipeline build is success but my the web app is not showing in the server URL, can someone tell me where I missed?

```
2020-04-20T14:01:09.3660179Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy War to Azure App Service
2020-04-20T14:01:09.3766431Z 
==============================================================================
2020-04-20T14:01:09.3766892Z Task         : Azure App Service deploy
2020-04-20T14:01:09.3767548Z Description  : Deploy to Azure App Service a web, mobile, or API app 
using Docker, Java, .NET, .NET Core, Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby
2020-04-20T14:01:09.3767944Z Version      : 4.163.5
2020-04-20T14:01:09.3768213Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-04-20T14:01:09.3768522Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azureappservicetroubleshooting
2020-04-20T14:01:09.3768901Z 
==============================================================================
2020-04-20T14:01:10.5416719Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'jpetstore01'
2020-04-20T14:01:13.1232245Z Package deployment using WAR Deploy initiated.
2020-04-20T14:01:28.4292592Z Deploy logs can be viewed at 
https://jpetstore01.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/9d03f1b9973b489e898d2aedfd5f7129/log
2020-04-20T14:01:28.4294018Z Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
2020-04-20T14:01:34.2874810Z Successfully updated App Service configuration details
2020-04-20T14:01:36.5781456Z Successfully updated deployment History at 
https://jpetstore01.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/41587391294722
2020-04-20T14:01:38.3127393Z App Service Application URL: http://jpetstore01.azurewebsites.net
2020-04-20T14:01:41.0462523Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy War to Azure App Service
```

This is my pipeline log, It is saying deployment successfull but i am not able to get the web app in http://jpetstore01.azurewebsites.net. can someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you checked that the file is where it should be? Could you please show here some information from your app server logs?

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: Yeah, My .WAR file is in the right location.  I have build my Java program using MAVEN and created that package, and then stored it in the "Target" folder.  Now while deploying it , it is not showing any error but it is not appearing in the website.

Comment: @Jason No, still getting nothing on the website

Comment: @LoGan Your application should not have been deployed successfully, right?

Answer (score 0):

From the logs shared by @LoGan, it appears that the war file was deployed successfully by the Azure DevOps task, but the application is running into some errors during startup.

Please navigate to `https://<sitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and then browse to the `D:\home\LogFiles\Application` directory. You should see one or more files named `catalina.*.log`. These are the log files generated by Tomcat, which should provide you some hints about what's going wrong with the application during startup.

Comment: Hi I navigated to the file as suggested, This two line i found little bit suspicious, can you suggest something?

21-Apr-2020 05:01:24.685 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/home/tomcat/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
21-Apr-2020 05:01:24.699 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.validateFile Problem with directory [/home/tomcat/lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]

Comment: Those are just warnings that say you don't have any jars in /home/tomcat/lib that you want Tomcat to load, which is normal. The error is something else. If you inspect the entire catalina.*.log file, you should spot some errors.